# Unexplainable write latency tempdb

Tags: sql-server-2016, tempdb

I have a virtual SQL Server 2016 SP2 CU2 with SAN storage. TempDB has 8 files. I know it is recommended to put TempDB on SSD but TempDB is hardly used so spinning disks are cheaper.
I've noticed that sometimes their is write latency on all my TempDB files of approx 200ms. I checked this using a snapshot on `sys.dm_io_virtual_file_stats` and calculated `io_stall_write_ms`/`num_of_writes`.

The first thing I did was look at `sys.dm_exec_query_stats` to check if there was a query with high number of spills but no such query. Next I wrote an extended event to look if there where queries executed on tempdb but also this returned nothing.

So where does the write latency come from? I decided to track the `file_write_completed` event on tempdb. Here I saw that on moment of the latency that session 22 wrote something with a size of 8192 (don't know the unit) to all files of tempdb. In `sys.dm_exec_sessions` the last command of this session was 'RESOURCE MONITOR'.
The first thing I did was checking `sys.dm_os_ring_buffers` with following query:

```
SELECT  
    EventTime, 
    record.value('(/Record/ResourceMonitor/Notification)[1]', 'varchar(max)') as [Type], 
    record.value('(/Record/ResourceMonitor/IndicatorsProcess)[1]', 'int') as [IndicatorsProcess], 
    record.value('(/Record/ResourceMonitor/IndicatorsSystem)[1]', 'int') as [IndicatorsSystem], 
    record.value('(/Record/MemoryRecord/AvailablePhysicalMemory)[1]', 'bigint')/1024. AS [Avail Phys Mem, MB], 
    record.value('(/Record/MemoryRecord/AvailableVirtualAddressSpace)[1]', 'bigint') AS [Avail VAS, Kb] 
FROM ( 
    SELECT 
        DATEADD (ss, (-1 * ((cpu_ticks / CONVERT (float, ( cpu_ticks / ms_ticks ))) - [timestamp])/1000), GETDATE()) AS EventTime, 
        CONVERT (xml, record) AS record 
    FROM sys.dm_os_ring_buffers 
    CROSS JOIN sys.dm_os_sys_info 
    WHERE ring_buffer_type = 'RING_BUFFER_RESOURCE_MONITOR') AS tab 
ORDER BY EventTime DESC;
```

But again the result of the query didn't match with the moment of latency.

I also monitored the tempdb-drive with perfmon, using the counters 'Avg. Disk sec/Write' and 'Current Disk Queue Length'. On moment of latency the latency was 6ms and the queue length was 18.

I ran CrystalDiskMark and this is the avg result of multiple runs:

```
╔═════════════╦═══════════╦═════════╦══════════╦═══════╗
║             ║ seq Q32T1 ║ 4k q8T8 ║ 4K Q32T1 ║ 4Q1T1 ║
╠═════════════╬═══════════╬═════════╬══════════╬═══════╣
║ Read(MB/s)  ║ 1596,57   ║ 505,77  ║ 336,27   ║ 20,94 ║
║ Write(MB/s) ║ 591,01    ║ 127,6   ║ 87,87    ║ 2,74  ║
╚═════════════╩═══════════╩═════════╩══════════╩═══════╝
```

After some extended research I discovered that on moment of latency the lazy writer process starts flushing pages to disk. If I understand correctly, SQL Server removes the least used pages (dirty and clean) from the buffer pool when memory is needed.
So If above is correct, I should see high number of physical reads at moment of latency, this I will investigate further.
Also at moment of latency there are no checkpoints running.


This is my conclusion so far:

- Resource Monitor is writing to Tempdb (detected with extended events, what/why is written I don't know)
- Lazy Writer process is flushing pages from  bufferpool because memory is needed.
  (I don't think this can cause write latency on Tempdb)

All this looks like signs of memory pressure to me.
But what I don't understand is why is this causing write latency on Tempdb?
What can I do to investigate this problem further?

Comment: What makes you think that 'TempDB is hardly ever used'?

Comment: Almost no queries are executed using tempdb, no spills, our monitoring tool shows almost any usage of tempdb.

Comment: Is this local or SAN storage? Are you seeing 15 second IO warnings in the error log?

Comment: @sp_BlitzErik: the server is on SAN Storage but no IO warnings are present in the error log.

Comment: The cause is likely the path from the server to the SAN. I'd check with the SAN admins about the speed and number of connections. If you're using like 1Gb iSCSI, that's gonna suck when you try to do anything that touches tempdb, like run CHECKDB.

Comment: @sp_BlitzErik: we're not using iSCSI but fiber channel. It's a virtual machine, I moved it to different ESX-servers but no difference. The latency spikes occur during the day, nothing 'special' is running on that moment

Comment: Okay, run Crystal Disk Mark and see if the results match the throughput you should be getting from it.

Comment: Frederik: do you have any triggers? any uses of the `OUTPUT` clause in any query? any level of "snapshot isolation" enabled? any temp tables or table variables? Any TVPs (table-valued parameters)? Any multi-statement TVFs? All of those things (and others) use tempdb. Are you watching for file auto-grow events, especially if you did not enable instant file initialization when installing the instance? are you watching for CHECKPOINT operations on tempdb?

Comment: @SolomonRutzky: No triggers are used, snapshot isolation is not used. TVP and TVF aren't used either. No auto-grow events. IFI is enabled. I also updated my answer with new findings